# Why does Redis C# client method .getById() return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, servicestack, repository-pattern

I'm building a simple blog application in Asp.Net MVC and I want to use a Redis database.

I have created a repository for my Users class that contains a few methods (create, getbyid and update). The probelm is the **GetById(long id)** method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ServiceStack.Redis;
using Domain.Entities;
using RedisDataLayer.AbstractRepository;
using System.Linq;

namespace RedisDataLayer.ConcreteRepository
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly IRedisClient _redisClient;

        public UserRepository(IRedisClient redisClient)
        {
            _redisClient = redisClient;
        }

        public User Create(User user)
        {
            var redisUsers = _redisClient.As<User>();

            user.UserId = redisUsers.GetNextSequence();
            redisUsers.Store(user);

            return user;
        }



        public User GetById(long id)
        {
            var redisUsers = _redisClient.As<User>();

            User returnUser;

            returnUser = redisUsers.GetById(id);

            return returnUser;
        }

        public User Update(User user)
        {
            var redisUsers = _redisClient.As<User>();

            User savedUser = redisUsers.GetById(user.UserId);


            savedUser.Username = user.Username;
            savedUser.Password = user.Password;
            savedUser.UserId = user.UserId;

            foreach (var blogId in user.BlogIds)
            {
                savedUser.BlogIds.Add(blogId);
            }

            redisUsers.Store(savedUser);

            return savedUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this method `returnUser = redisUsers.GetById(id);` always return null? I've been trying to find an answer on StackOverflow and other places but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetById()` API (and all other ServiceStack.Redis Typed Client APIs) expect the POCOs to have a unique Id in an `Id` property.

So you should change your User model to use `Id` instead of `UserId`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I've been banging my head for 2 hours about this.